# How to pass a dynamic port to the Websockets-gateway in NestJS?

Tags: websocket, configuration, nestjs, decorator

I wanted to dynamically set the Websockets-gateway port from config in NestJS. Below is my **websockets-gateway** code.

```
import { WebSocketGateway } from '@nestjs/websockets';

const WS_PORT = parseInt(process.env.WS_PORT);

@WebSocketGateway(WS_PORT)
export class WsGateway {
  constructor() {
    console.log(WS_PORT);
  }
}
```

But the WS_PORT is always NaN.

This is my **bootstrap** function insdie main.ts :

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: false });
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  initAdapters(app);
  await app.listen(configService.get(HTTP_PORT), () => {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + configService.get(HTTP_PORT));
  });
}
```

Below is my **app.module.ts** :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: './src/config/dev.env',
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    RedisModule,
    SocketStateModule,
    RedisPropagatorModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        secret: configService.get<string>(JWT_SECRET_KEY),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [WsGateway, AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I put a console log in the Gateway constructor to print the value of 'WS_PORT' but it's always NaN.

```
[Nest] 13252  - 10/04/2021, 5:05:34 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
NaN
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I could not find a way to add dynamic data to the decorator. So to be able to dynamically choose the port and other configurations I had to:

- Create an adapter for socket-io:
- Tell NestJs to use the new adapter

`SocketIoAdapter.ts`

```js
import { INestApplicationContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import { ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

export class SocketIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
constructor(
  private app: INestApplicationContext,
  private configService: ConfigService,
) {
  super(app);
}

createIOServer(port: number, options?: ServerOptions) {
  port = this.configService.get<number>('SOCKETIO.SERVER.PORT');
  const path = this.configService.get<string>('SOCKETIO.SERVER.PATH');
  const origins = this.configService.get<string>(
    'SOCKETIO.SERVER.CORS.ORIGIN',
  );
  const origin = origins.split(',');
  options.path = path;
  options.cors = { origin };
  const server = super.createIOServer(port, options);
  return server;
}
}
```

Now, you need to edit the `main.ts` to use the adapter

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { SocketIoAdapter } from './socket-io/socket-io.adapter';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  const hosts = configService.get<string>('CORS.HOST');
  const hostsArray = hosts.split(',');
  app.enableCors({
    origin: hostsArray,
    credentials: true,
  });
//Here you use the adapter and sent the config service
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new SocketIoAdapter(app, configService));
  await app.listen(4300);
}
bootstrap();
```

In this case I set the port and the cors origin, here an example of the conf file (using .env)
`env.local`

```
SOCKETIO.SERVER.PORT=4101
SOCKETIO.SERVER.PATH=
SOCKETIO.SERVER.CORS.ORIGIN=http://localhost:4200,http://localhost.com:8080
```

Here a link to config service [Config Service NestJs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-the-configservice)

Comment: This is neat.  Thanks you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it relatively straightforward if you decorate the `Gateway` before `app.init` is called:

1. Import the class in `main.ts`
2. Get an instance of your `ConfigurationService`
3. Manually call the decorator on the class with the config data

```js
function decorateGateway(class_, config) {
  // Just calling the decorator as a function with the class
  // as argument does the same as `@WebSocketGateway`
  WebSocketGateway({
    cors: {
      origin: config.get("websocket.cors.origin"),
    }
  })(class_)
}

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {});
  const config = app.get(ConfigService);
  decorateGateway(ChatGateway, config);
  ...
  app.init();
}
```

The tricky part with a `Gateway` is that it starts up together with the server, and the decorator metadata needs to be applied to the class earlier than for other components. You can do this in `main.ts` before `app.init`.

Answer (score 0):

```
port = this.configService.get<number>('SOCKETIO.SERVER.PORT');
```

In my case I found its return string(from .env), port gets 'string' but not 'number',

but if put `parseInt(this.configService.get<number>('SOCKETIO.SERVER.PORT'), 10);`
then it is ok

Mind that socket-io ports must be the same on server & client side

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dotenv package(used by @nestjs/config module) and then import your config file in the websocket module

config/env.ts:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

export default () => {
  return {
    wsPort: parseInt(process.env.WS_PORT),
  }
}
```

events.gateway.ts:

```
import envSetup from '../config/env';
@WebSocketGateway(envSetup.wsPort)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the existing `IoAdapter`.

```js
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import { INestApplicationContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Server, ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';
import { CorsOptions } from 'cors';

export class Adapter extends IoAdapter {
  constructor(
    appOrHttpServer: INestApplicationContext,
    private readonly corsOptions: CorsOptions,
  ) {
    super(appOrHttpServer);
  }

  create(port: number, options?: ServerOptions): Server {
    return super.create(port, {
      ...options,
      cors: this.corsOptions,
    });
  }
}
```

Then, you need to use it in the `bootstrap` function.

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Adapter } from './chat/adapter';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);

  app.enableCors({
    origin: configService.get('FRONTEND_URL'),
  });

  app.useWebSocketAdapter(
    new Adapter(app, {
      origin: configService.get('FRONTEND_URL'),
    }),
  );

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

In my case, the `FRONTEND_URL` variable is the URL of my frontend application.

```
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:5173
```